# Linux Exim set return-path header automaticly using from header

Tags: linux, email, exim, spam-filter, return-path

I use Exim on a Centos distribution and have some problems with the mail sending. 
In order to make all the email pass the spam filters the "Return-path" and "Sender" headers have to be attached to each email.

What should I do in order to have "Return-path" and "Sender" headers added 
by Exim to be exactly the same as the "From" header created by my mail 
client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `local_from_check` to false in the main section of your config.  That will keep Exim from adding a Sender: header.  If you want to be able to specify your own Sender: headers, then set `local_sender_retain` to true.

If you set `untrusted_set_sender` then your mail-client can specify the envelope sender (which on delivery is often placed into a new `Return-Path:` header) too.

If your client is not specifying a sender and you want Exim to fake it up for you, then you probably want to have the Router which sends outbound mail set the errors_to option which will rewrite the SMTP envelope sender for you.  That's trickier to get right, so see if the others, and client config, are enough for you.

You don't mention which mail-client you're using.

Comment: i wanted to add it regarding of the email client used by the user, but the errors_to was exacly what i needed